# Retrieving specific fixtures in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, fixtures

I have a YML file containing fixtures for a Rails model (Comment) which looks like this (pardon the formatting):

> comment_a:
>    id: 1
>    text: 'foo'
>    visible: false
>
> comment_b:
>    id: 2
>    text: 'bar'
>    visible: true
>
> comment_c:
>    id: 3
>    text: 'baz'
>    visible: true

I know that I can select an individual Comment fixture like so:

> comments(:comment_a)

In one of my acceptance tests, I want to find all the Comments which have visible = true. How do I select a set of Comments that meet certain criteria so I can iterate over them afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need made the request by your ActiveRecord Object. `Comments.all(:conditions => {:visible => true})`